# jquery validation for unique with dynamic name of input

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have used following jquery code

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("unique", function(value, element, params) {
    var prefix = params;
    var selector = jQuery.validator.format("[name!='{0}'][name^='{1}'][unique='{1}']", element.name, prefix);
    var matches = new Array();
    $(selector).each(function(index, item) {
        if (value == $(item).val()) {
            matches.push(item);
        }
    });

    return matches.length == 0;
}, "Value is not unique.");

jQuery.validator.classRuleSettings.unique = {
    unique: true
};
$("#myform").validate();

$("#validate").click(function() {
    $("#myform").valid();
});
```

but due to same input name its not working properly, check here https://jsfiddle.net/bgzBY/147/

but If I will use different name than that will work,check  http://jsfiddle.net/mysteryh/bgzBY/

So how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** use the same `name` on more than one input field.  There is no workaround for this requirement of the plugin.  (It's how the plugin keeps track of the input elements.)

> So how to fix it?

You **must** use a unique `name` on every input. `currency[1]`, `currency[2]`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

It has nothing to do with your names. Your script is not loading properly. Blocked loading mixed active content "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.min.js" This is the error shown in console.

Comment: It has nothing to do with this.  He's duplicating the `name` on every field and the plugin cannot work this way.